# How to make the variable empty if the Jobject is empty in C#

Tags: c#, list, json.net

I am getting a Null reference exception when the Jobject is empty.

```
var subjects = item.SelectToken("$.subjects").ToObject<List<JObject>>()
```

I am want to set var subjects as empty when Jobject empty without throwing an error.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var subjects = item.SelectToken("$.subjects")?.ToObject<List<JObject>>() ?? new List<JObject>();
```

### List<...>

List is a collection and you need to define what's in the List. Like `List<string>`, `List<object>`, or, for your code, `List<JObject>`.

### SelectToken("$.subjects")?.

This means that if `SelectToken` returns null, it stops there without doing `.ToObject`, and returns **null**.

The issue here is that `SelectToken` will return null when it can't find any object, and when you do `.ToObject` on a `null` you get a `NullException`. So one'd usually check if an object is null before further using its properties or functions.

The question mark - **Null-Conditional Operator** ([Official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)) is a quick syntactic sugar to achieve that, without having to write conditions like

```
if (... == null) 
{ ...convert to list... } 
else 
{ ...make empty list...}
```

### ?? new List()

Not sure what you mean by *empty*, if you don't want **null**, but an empty `List`, [Null-coalescing Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) might come to help.

It means that if the statement before `??` is **null**, returns the statement after `??` instead.

For example, `string a = b ?? c` means:

```
string a = b != null ? b : c
```

But notice that `a` still can be **null** if `c` is **null**.

It's also a syntactic sugar to help you avoid writing long statements for these checks are frequently needed.